# About web addresses

Tags: url, web

My question is about URL and Web. Sometimes i see URL as so:
**www.myweb.com/user.php?name=mark**
I understand that this way you can like take data from database where name is mark and display on site.

but other way is see is like this:
**www.myweb.com/user/mark**

As i see it, it file named mark inside user folder, that somehow then displays from database all the info about guy named Mark, but what is really going on? How is it done so? Is it something to do with XML? When to use it so? Why to use it so?

I dont know even what to search in google, so any link is helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common technique called url-rewriting that the web server can perform.

Wordpress does this and it translates

```
http://example.com/2013/04/27/foo
```

into something like

```
http://example.com/index.php?url=2013/04/27/foo
```

You can read up on in generalities on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

Comment: It doesn't answer the question; it just points to an external resource to find the answer.  Hence, it is more appropriate as a comment.  More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

`user` and `mark` are not "folders", but simply parts of the URL.

Some web servers follow a convention to look in the folder /user/mark (relative to some root folder) and serve a document from there.

However, it is becoming increasingly common for web platforms to interpret the URL differently.  The exact interpretation is depends on the specific web platform.

Such web platforms simply map parts of the URL to server resources using a platform-defined convention.

In ASP.Net (the platform I am most familiar with), that mapping is called [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX).

> ASP.NET routing enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to specific files in a Web site. Because the URL does not have to map to a file, you can use URLs that are descriptive of the user's action and therefore are more easily understood by users.

Answer (score 0):

If talking about common Apache servers, the webserver has a file called `.htaccess` or another one `httpd.conf` capable of using Apache's built-in `mod_rewrite` module for URL rewriting. The exact ways to do this can be specified in these files using `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives. The new URIs are just aliases for old ones. (There don't have to be actual folders for the given route)

Comment: that depends on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause of using .htacces
This is a file that removes the query string and makes pretty URLs

Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)subject=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/product.php$ $1/%2? [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)((?:[+\s]+).*)$ $1-$2$3 [DPI,N]
RewriteRule ^([^+\s]+)(?:[+\s]+)([^+\s]+)$ $1-$2 [R=301,DPI,L]
```

Comment: He never said it was Apache...  Certainly a common web server for PHP resources but not the only one.

Comment: Basically you just got to change one file and then it makes pretty URLs? Dont belive it so simple, but you never know if you dont ask :P

Comment: I think that over 70% of webservers are using apache...in my country about 95% of the webservers use apache.
It was just an example...